# [interview] vs [interview-questions] vs [job-interview]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

I've submitted a suggestion to make [interview] and [job-interview] synonyms of [interview-questions]:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/interview-questions/synonyms

I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do, but [[interview]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interview) and [[job-interview]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/job-interview) are mostly filled with interview questions.

Tag counts:

- interview: 75 questions
- job-interview: 311 questions
- interview-questions: 910 questions

There's also:

- code-in-interview: 8 questions

Many of these questions are tagged by more than one of the above. I believe we should do some type of grouping is necessary. Suggestions?

Comment: Follow-up question: Do programming/puzzle interview questions still fit best on Stack Overflow, or would they be better moved to Programmers?  I don't really have a strong opinion either way, but just thought I'd ask.

Comment: @Bill Many of them involve code.

Comment: That's good enough for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `[interview-questions]` is the right tag.  Normally I'd be against "question" being anywhere in a tag since it seems redundant on a Q&A site, but I think this is a special case.  Since programming/puzzle interview questions are sort of a special breed, and we seriously don't want any other kinds of general questions about interviews on Stack Overflow, it probably is best to make more general tags a synonym.

Comment: Could we get some votes on the synonyms?

Comment: @marcog: I was waiting on others to weigh in, but since the question and answer got nothing but upvotes with no dissenting opinions I went ahead and approved them.