# Missing tag badge

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, tag-badges

I have [103 points on interview-questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/interview-questions/topusers), but no badge. I reached 100 about 30 hours ago, and had at least two tag-badge updates since then (as I was awarded other tag-badges).

Is it possibly related to the recent [addition of tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73239/interview-vs-interview-questions-vs-job-interview)? Or should I just be more patient?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange tag-badge behavior for scala tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71904/strange-tag-badge-behavior-for-scala-tag)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You only have 11 answers provided -- you need 20 non-wiki answers for the bronze badge.

Comment: Oh, didn't know about that. Thanks!