# Add required number of posts to tag badge descriptions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, tag-badges

Tag badges have a required score and a required number of answers, but the required number of answers isn't included on [the individual badge's description page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/300/arrays), only in the sidebar of [the tag badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags).

[image]

[image]

I didn't notice the sidebar, and was confused about why I hadn't been awarded a new badge until I found [this question from another confused user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74318/missing-tag-badge).

I would like to see the full requirements included on tag badge pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will go out in the next build for new badges (the descriptions are persisted), and an update on existing descriptions will be run shortly after to correctly reflect the "at least 20", "at least 80" and "at least 200" answer counts required for bronze, silver and gold, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

### My take on this: YES, please!

The tag badges specifically reward higher-reputation users that make a *significant* contribution to a topic on the site.  The lack of clarity in leaving out the requirement of "in at least 20 non-CW answers" will only generate angst among users who feel they've worked hard to meet the criterion only to learn that they could still be several answers away from attaining the badge.  (As witnessed by the questions on meta)

### My meandering reasoning

My suspicion is that this was omitted to increase the enticement or mysterious behavior?  I understand the desire to [keep the badges a bit mysterious](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/a-bevy-of-new-badges/).  However, I don't think this omission falls under the four stated criteria:

- What activity is this badge referring to?
- How do I perform this activity?
- Why is this activity important and necessary?
- Who should normally perform this activity, and when?

The omission of a requirement will not further entice users -- (especially from the tag specific page [like this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/81/bug)).  In addition, the tag badges *already create some mystery because they fairly rarely show up under the 'Recently awarded badges'*:

Lastly, the tag badges are already a bit off the beaten path.  When you click [Badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges), you then also have to click the tags tab:

[image]

Comment: For the record: I wish that I could hide the second half of this answer under the heading "My meandering reasoning" [With an arrow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104008/152009).