# expandable text in answers for version b and for explanation

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could we please have a clickable arrow to expand hidden content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104008/could-we-please-have-a-clickable-arrow-to-expand-hidden-content)

What about links in answer that stands for showing additional information?

I have [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11473953/669677) on SO, and later I saw that the code I have inserted into the answer, that does not work in more complex case. I'd like insert the updated source too, for those who is also in complex case. I'd like to make available both version, because I think the first one is great in basic case, while the second one is less elegant but necessary in complex case.
If I would insert both code, the answer would be too long and impenetrable* (*I don't know if this is the right word , I mean: people would think - why are there two codes?)

It would be great if I could collapse the second code part ("version B"), and if somebody would like to see it, he/she could expand it (e.g. with a slide down effect).

This feature would also useful to show an explanation of code, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3826997/669677), where the source is enough but somebody may would like to know how it works.

Comment: @Arjan might be correct, if you (user65130) also agree it's a duplicate please flag your post for moderator attention, moderator can "undo" the bounty and close the question. Anyway, personally I don't think the few cases where such thing is required justify the cost (development time) and complexity of such a thing.

Comment: I have reported it as duplicate.